# Issue with loading a .dat file

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.7

According to my instructor, the data file below 'galaxy_data.dat' should contain 3 columns, the first with the names of the galaxies (ignored) and the second and third with the galaxy's recessional velocities and extinction of light in the milky way. Each column should contain data for *8* galaxies, but when i try and put the data into arrays using np.loadtxt, and print these arrays, i'm only given two bits of data.

```
data_array9 = np.loadtxt("galaxy_data.dat", dtype= "float", usecols = (1,2))
recessional_velocity = data_array9[1]
V_band_extinction = data_array9[2]
```

and when i print the two arrays;

```
in: recessional_velocity
Out: array([1.51e+03, 4.34e-02]) (two bits of data)

in: V_band_extinction
Out: array([1.152e+03, 7.750e-02]) (two bits again)
```

I don't know if this is something wrong with my code, or if the file is just messed up. Help!

Edit: I converted the data file to a text file and this is what it looks like:

> ```
> #Galaxy       Recession       A_{V,MW}
> #Name     Velocity (km/s)     (mag)
> NGC3627       427         0.0992
> NGC3982       1510            0.0434
> NGC4496A  1152            0.0775
> NGC4527       1152            0.0682
> NGC4536       1152            0.0558
> NGC4639       1152            0.0806
> NGC5253       170         0.1736
> IC4182        303         0.0434
> ```

Comment: You aren't printing the two columns, but rather two rows, each with the two values you see in the file.  To see columns use `data_array9[:,0]` and `[:,1]`.

Comment: thanks that fixed it. im so new to coding, but that was very obvious!

Answer (score 1):

You are indexing wrongly - you get rows not columns.

Try this:

```
t = '''#Galaxy       Recession       A_{V,MW}
#Name     Velocity (km/s)     (mag)
NGC3627       427         0.0992
NGC3982       1510            0.0434
NGC4496A  1152            0.0775
NGC4527       1152            0.0682
NGC4536       1152            0.0558
NGC4639       1152            0.0806
NGC5253       170         0.1736
IC4182        303         0.0434'''  

with open("f.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(t)


import numpy as np

data_array9 = np.loadtxt("f.txt", dtype= "float", usecols = (1,2))


# recessional_velocity 
print(data_array9[:,0])   # [ 427. 1510. 1152. 1152. 1152. 1152.  170.  303.]

# V_band_extinction 
print(data_array9[:,1])   # [0.0992 0.0434 0.0775 0.0682 0.0558 0.0806 0.1736 0.0434]
```